# Batch/Macro code to get latest file from FTP site

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, ftp, command-prompt

We have a shared FTP site with a daily file upload which I need to download and run checks over. I'm simply trying to automate the process. The FTP file is something like `name_20150901.xml`.

So far I have a batch file to get the file but I can't figure out how to get the latest. Here is my code:

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open ftp.site.com
<user>
<pass>
lcd my local direc
binary
get todaysfile_20150901.xml
```

What changes do I need to read the files and get the newest one? My end goal is to have a macro that calls this and then reads the file that's grabbed from the FTP and runs my checks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to select the most recent file with the `ftp.exe`.

- If you know that the file has today's timestamp, you can generate the script dynamically with the today's timestamp. You can use the `DATE` environment variable, though it has its caveats. A more reliable (and complex) way is to use the `wmic os get LocalDateTime`.

  See [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/850848)
- If you can determine the latest file alphabetically, you can:

  - run the `ftp.exe` with the `ls` command redirected to a file
  - sort the files by alphabet in a descending order
  - read the first line
  - generate a download script for the second `ftp.exe` run

- [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) can download the files created within the last 24-hours (1 day):

  ```
  winscp.com /command ^
      "open ftp://user:pass@ftp.site.com/" ^
      "lcd c:\my\local\direc" ^
      "get *>=1D" ^
      "exit"
  ```
- If you really need to download the latest file (by timestamp), you probably need some more advanced scripting.

  For example there's a guide available for [downloading the most recent file with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

  *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*